# Setting variable to its own value's value dynamically - Possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Using TSQL

Trying to set the @DynamicValue = 23 which is the parameter it is "equal" to in the below but can't figure it out.

```
DECLARE @DynamicValue VARCHAR(MAX) = '@PersonID';
DECLARE @PersonID INT = 23;
DECLARE @PlaceID INT = 48;
DECLARE @ThingID INT = 29;
DECLARE @nSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @nSQL = N'SELECT @Parameter2 = ' + CAST(@DynamicValue AS VARCHAR(MAX));
-- This is where the error is. If I used @PersonID here it would be fine but I want this to be dynamic

EXEC sp_executesql @nSQL,
                   N'@Parameter2 NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
                   @Parameter2 = @DynamicValue OUTPUT;

SELECT @DynamicValue;
```

Any ideas? Different approaches?

Comment: `@DynamicValue` is a string.  The referenced variable is an `int`.  What you want to do is probably unnecessary to solve a real-world problem.

Comment: You can't access a variable declared outside of dynamic SQL unless it's passed by parameter.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Can't be done. Variables can't cross scope boundaries and there is not a single T-SQL function that can grab metadata on local declarations. Even dynamic SQL won't help here, since you can only ever pass values, not references to them, or names. If you absolutely wanted to you could get needlessly clever with tables, since you could refer to columns across scopes. I use the word "needlessly" here with reason.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've clearly simplified the example I used. The actual procedure is using a cursor to run through different tests and execute them dynamically. Each test is a stored procedure that accepts different parameters so I've set up a parameter mapping table. There is another cursor that runs through each parameter, sets the value and adds it to a parameter string. To make this dynamic we need to find the value of the parameter based on a mapping table which is already defined. The MappedParameter will be set to a parameter name which we need to grab the value from.

Comment: As far as alternatives go, it looks like you're trying to have code make some sort of dynamic choice based on a parameter. Consider not using `INT` locals and storing that data in an actual table, whether physically or as a table variable. Looking up values by key dynamically is easy in that case, since it is after all what SQL was designed to do.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I kind of figured this was the answer but I just wanted to confirm that there wasn't another way around this. Thank you for the detailed and informative response.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yep that was the other approach I was going to use - build out a temp table that included each ParameterName and Value. Thank you very much

Comment: If you need to dynamically call dynamic code, use the time-honored tradition of adding another layer. Generate the `sp_executesql` statements that perform the stored procedure calls dynamically as well, before executing them. Right now you seem to have one too few layers, where you're trying to call the sprocs directly (even though that's not possible because you don't know their parameter lists yet). If you can cobble up a query that generates the statements to run as dynamic SQL (with a `CROSS JOIN` over the param values), you should need a cursor to run the tests only at the very end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to pass all the parameters into the dynamic batch that performs the assignment.

Like this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicValue VARCHAR(MAX) = '@PersonID';

DECLARE @PersonID INT = 23;
DECLARE @PlaceID INT = 48;
DECLARE @ThingID INT = 29;
DECLARE @nSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @nSQL = N'set @Parameter2 = ' + CAST(@DynamicValue AS VARCHAR(MAX));

EXEC sp_executesql @nSQL,
                   N'@PersonID int, @PlaceID int, @ThingID int, @Parameter2 NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
                   @PersonID = @PersonID, @PlaceID = @PlaceID, @ThingID = @ThingID, @Parameter2  = @DynamicValue OUTPUT;

SELECT @DynamicValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

EzLo's comment above that a variable declared outside of dynamic SQL can't be accessed made me rewrite your code in the following way, seems to work:

```
SET @nSQL = N'DECLARE @PersonID INT = ' + CAST(@PersonID as varchar)
         +' DECLARE @PlaceID INT = ' + CAST(@PlaceID as varchar)
         +' DECLARE @ThingID INT ='  + CAST(@ThingID as varchar)
         +' SELECT @Parameter2 = ' + CAST(@DynamicValue AS VARCHAR(MAX));
```

Comment: Yes even if you changed it to:

`SET @nSQL = N'SELECT @Parameter2 = ' + CAST(@PersonID AS VARCHAR(MAX));'

it would work but we are trying to make it grab the value from the DynamicValue parameter, not hardcode the variable it is set to.

Comment: Then declare all your parameters inside dynamic sql statement. I edited my answer

Comment: The values will need to be redefined - no?
EDIT: Nevermind - I see what you did. Thank you

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, I did not change anything in your code except '@nSQL' definition part. Pass '@PersonId', '@ThingID' or '@PlaceID' - it is returning correct value.

Comment: Yep this is great - Thank you!

Comment: Please, consider marking the answer that helped you as an accepted answer to help future readers (although every answer here deserves it). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see:

```
DECLARE @DynamicValue VARCHAR(MAX) = '@PersonID';
DECLARE @PersonID INT = 23;
DECLARE @PlaceID INT = 48;
DECLARE @ThingID INT = 29;

SELECT @DynamicValue = CAST(CASE @DynamicValue 
    WHEN '@PersonID' THEN @PersonID
    WHEN '@PlaceID' THEN @PlaceID
    WHEN '@ThingID' THEN @ThingID END as VARCHAR(MAX))
SELECT @DynamicValue
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do the same trick, but you still would have to list all your parameters:

```
DECLARE @DynamicValue VARCHAR(MAX) = '@PersonID';
DECLARE @PersonID INT = 23;
DECLARE @PlaceID INT = 48;
DECLARE @ThingID INT = 29;

DECLARE @DynamicValues TABLE (Parameter VARCHAR(MAX), Value INT)
INSERT INTO @DynamicValues VALUES 
('@PersonID',@PersonID),
('@PlaceID',@PlaceID),
('@ThingID',@ThingID);

SELECT @DynamicValue = CAST(Value as VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM @DynamicValues WHERE Parameter = @DynamicValue
SELECT @DynamicValue
```